# phpize failed error pecl install imagick

Tags: php, centos7, imagemagick

We are trying to install the ImageMagick extension on PHP version 7.4 in our AWS ec2 Linux CentOS server using cli. ImageMagick extension was installed successfully.  We used `convert -version` to check the outcome.

The second step was to install the Imagick PHP extension.  We used `pecl install imagick` command. On executing the command following error displayed. The summary of error is given below:

> phpize failed, Php headers not found in /usr/xx php-devel required to execute command

I searched many forums, but I'm unable to get over this. What shall we do.

Comment: Did you install php-devel?

Comment: It appears that Amazon Linux 2 PHP 7.4 doesn't support imagick yet. They are having an issue with PECL extension build passing its own test suite. Amazon support is recommending go back to PHP 7.3 extras until it is ready... https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=941096